# Override External CSS

Tags: css, overriding, external

How does one override external `CSS` in `PHP` - My local `CSS` takes changes via important - but this one must be removed

It's not as straight forward as in `HTML`

I want to do this `*position: none !important;}`

On the external path the `CSS` is:  `position:  absolute ;}`

Once this is removed in developer mode from browser the positioning goes to where I need it be.

These work but don't put it where I need it to be -

```
absolute
fixed
relative
static
inherit
```

Comment: You need to show some real HTML and CSS code and explain in which sense you need to override it and what you mean by doing it “in PHP”. (If PHP is somehow relevant, the question should be tagged with “php” too.) Also not that `position: none` is not valid CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can use the *{position: none !important;} styles form your index.php file.

Example:
<style type="text/css">

* {
    position: none !important;
}
</style>

because the inline styles has the high priority. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should invest some of your time into studying [css-specificity](http://designshack.net/articles/css/what-the-heck-is-css-specificity/). When it comes to overwriting another CSS rule, there is a whole CSS point system that gives every CSS selector points. Points for using direct child selector, points for using inline styles, classes, id's and more.

However, the `!important` is Superman, it can beat up almost anything. [Another good source about this subject.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity)